MokList error: Volume full; cannot boot Asus laptop
I have an old ASUS laptop. The SDD is fully clean, empty. The laptop used to have Windows on it.
Now I want to install only Ubuntu.
The error I get is this and I cannot boot at all, nothing:

Reading different posts lead me to these possible solutions:

Delete all secure boot variables and do F9 optimized defaults to reset all keys to factory settings? see image (2) 
Do SET new platform keys (KP)? see image (3) 
Disable secure boot but how exactly? see image (1) 
The final solution after I did one of above three options is to boot from liveUSB to try Ubuntu, then I do following to remove boot entries (all then because I do not need any, everything can be removed!):

sudo apt-get install efibootmgr    
sudo efibootmgr -v    
sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B

Which solution is the right one to do because I am not sure about the risks involved?

If the last one works then I'd argue it's the preferred method. And is risk-free.

@ChanganAuto - the last one does not work because I have no way to boot any OS (from a liveUSB).

So disable secure boot and then do it, if you intend to re-enable secure boot later.

@ChanganAuto - disabling secure boot helped nothing. Only remedy seems to be to delete all secure boot variables and then reinstall them, but how to go about that exactly? delete really everything and then f9 optimized default which reinstalls them or what?

Probably, I don't know details about such operations. Never had to do it.

See this answer. It worked for me.
